# Why this vertical distance in annotation of tikz mindmap?

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, vertical-spacing

In the following minimal example

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every annotation/.style = {draw, font = \Large}]
  \node [annotation] at (4,4) {\parskip 0pt \parindent 0pt  %
    \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt\parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt\itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
      \item Item%
    \endlist};
  \node [annotation] at (2,2) {Hallo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get a vertical distance before the list which, in my understanding, should not be there.

[image]

Why is it there?
Is it a bug or a feature I do not understand?
What is the proper way to remove it? I cannot use `enumitem` - this is the MWE but the original document has a situation which is incompatible with `enumitem`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With use of the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
annotation/.style = {draw, rounded corners, font = \Large,
                     text width=5em}    % <---
                        ]
\node [annotation] {\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*, before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}]
                      \item Item
                      \end{itemize}
                      };
\node [annotation] at (0,-1) {Hallo};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Proposed solution is not intended to use in beamer. For it is better suit to enclose `itemize` in `minipage:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
annotation/.style = {draw, rounded corners, font = \Large,
                     text width=6em}    % <---
                        ]
\node [annotation] {\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
                    \begin{itemize}
                      \item Item
                    \end{itemize}
                    \end{minipage}
                   };
\node [annotation] at (0,-1) {Hallo};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Above solution work well also in `standalone` document as well as in `article` and other default LaTeX document classes.

[image]

Comment: Very helpful since it pointed to \baselineskip. Problematic since it uses enumitem, which is incompatible with beamer. Problematic as it pulls up the list by a fixed distance - so it does not work as part of a macro where we do not know if the annotation contents starts with an itemize (where we need to pull up) or has normal text before the itemize (in which case we do not need to pull up). But it pointed me to a nice solution!

Comment: @Nobody-Knows-I-am-a-Dog, sorry, but you not say anything about your real document. I didn't provide an general solution, only for your particular problem. See addendum to answer (will appear ASAP).

Comment: If the issue is the reputation here, I can accept your answer if that is helpful for you :-)  (although it uses enumitem, which actually was a stated no-go criterion in the original question).  The problem with "original documents" usually is that they do not meet the MWE criteria. Looking forward to the addendum. Still curious why 0.5\basekineskip looks better than removing \baselineskip completely.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Zarko pointed into a good direction. It looks like the vertical space is connected with `\baselineskip`. If I `\baselineskip0pt` the problem is gone (however there are unwanted side effects in other places). Doing a negative `\vspace` of `0.5\baselineskip` is aesthetically the most pleasing solution but it has another unwanted side effect: I want to have this as part of a macro construction and do not want to have to manually distinguish different situations (one does not see this in the MWE, it only becomes obvious in the macro construction).

The solution I will now adopt for my macro packge is to use a `\par\nointerlineskip` as this works independently on how the contents continues. In terms of the MWE this means:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every annotation/.style = {draw, font = \Large}]
  \node [annotation] at (4,4) {\par\nointerlineskip%
    \list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt\parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt\itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
      \item Item%
    \endlist};
  \node [annotation] at (2,2) {\par\nointerlineskip%
  Hallo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and it produces

[image]

Comment: See addendum in my answer ...